# Selecting specific rows with multi-level indexes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am learning Python in DataCamp where I am in a course titled *Data Manipulation with pandas*

In an exercise I want to select some rows from a data frame but I get an error and I really don't understand the message of the error.

Here is the code

```
# Load packages
import pandas as pd

# Import data
sales = pd.read_pickle("https://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/5386/datasets/b0e855c644024f850a7df3fe8b7bf0e23f7bd2fc/walmart_sales.pkl.bz2", 'bz2')

print(sales)

# Create multi-level indexes
sales_ind = sales.set_index(["store", "type"])

print(sales_ind)

# Define the rows to select
rows_to_keep = [(1, "A"), (2, "B")]

print(rows_to_keep)

# Use .iloc to select the rows
print(sales_ind.loc[rows_to_keep])
```

The problem is when I run `print(sales_ind.loc[rows_to_keep])` where I get this error message `KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'` but I don't understand how to fix the code.

I am using `Python 3.7.6` and `pandas 1.0.0`

Comment: Hello @ALollz the data can be found here: https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-manipulation-with-pandas > DATASETS > __Walmart sales__ at the bottom of the web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out your problem and it is not a problem with `df.loc`, but instead with the data you provided. There is no value in your multiindex that matches the tuple `(2,'B')`.

You can see this if you try:

```
sales_ind.loc[(2,'B'),:]
```

which returns:

```
KeyError: (2, 'B')
```

while `(1,'A')` works just fine.

By the way, when selecting on a multiindex, I always recommend using `pd.IndexSlice`

Comment: Thank you very much @Lucas H. This thing was making me crazy. I appreciate your recommendation. I am learning Python so maybe at a initial phase I will make a lot of mistakes like this. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: the other trick to try always if you get errors like this with `df.loc` is to explicitly pass the columns you want as well as the rows. Sometimes pandas doesn't know what axis you are talking about unless you do that. So instead of `df.loc[row_list]` pass `df.loc[row_list,:]` or a specific list of columns. That's the first thing I always check when I get an error with `loc` these days.

Comment: Ok. @Lucas H I will take into account your recommendation. Thank you for sharing your experience!